# What is the best way to pull apart a list to find a single item

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

```
var failed = Client.FailedBuildsByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id).ToString();
```

This is how the list is created.  I am using TeamCity Sharp, and I'm a newbie.  What gets returned is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TeamCitySharp.DomainEntities.Build]
```

I want to find the string 'FAILURE' in the list.  How do I go about doing so?

Comment: a for loop, i=0;i<listlength;i++
match up a string "FAILURE" to the current index
--- will it be just the word failure or a sentence that may contain failure?

Comment: Why are you .ToString()?

Comment: I'm using ToString since, I reference it to status which is a string in my POCO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
bool failed = Client.FailedBuildsByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id).Any(b => b.ToString().Contains("FAILURE"))
```

I don't know the output of that class, but if `ToString()` does not, in fact, return the `Status` (or StatusText), do one of these instead:

```
//examine Status field
bool failed = Client.FailedBuildsByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id).Any(b => b.Status.Contains("FAILURE"))
```

or

```
//examine StatusText field
bool failed = Client.FailedBuildsByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id).Any(b => b.StatusText.Contains("FAILURE"))
```

Comment: +1 but from [the Build class source](https://github.com/stack72/TeamCitySharp/blob/master/src/TeamCitySharp/DomainEntities/Build.cs) it looks he'll want `b.Status.Contains("FAILURE")` or maybe `.StatusText` instead, not `.ToString()`

Comment: @Rup modified answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `Client.FailedBuildsByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id).ToString()` it is returning the name of the type of object returned from FailedBuildsByBuildConfigId.

Try

```
var failed = Client.FailedBuildsByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id).Where(b => b.Status == "FAILED");
```